# Adding tags into Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have changed my build tool from Maven to Gradle and want to know how to define the following tags in `build.gradle` file.

```
<developers>
    <developer>
        <email></email>
        <name></name>
        <timezone></timezone>
        <roles>
            <role></role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
</developers>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
    </license>
</licenses>
```

Answer (score 1):

via the [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
           pom {
              licenses {
                    license {
                        name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
                        url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id = 'johnd'
                        name = 'John Doe'
                        email = 'john.doe@example.com'
                    }
                }
           }
        }
   }
}
```